# iText XMLWorker Chinese

Tags: itext

I am evaluating itext for a project in which converts on the fly generated HTML document to pdf document. XMLWorker fits the bill completely. I am having trouble when my HTML document contains Chinese / Korean etc characters.

I have heard that in Itext we can use fonts without embedding them. I have seen the FontSelector example in which FontSelector enables us to use fonts without embedding them. The generated pdf prompts for downloading language pack from adobe site and this is what i want.

But i am not sure how will that work with XMLWorker. Any example or code snippet will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.micmiu.com/opensource/expdoc/itext-xml-worker-cn/
read this post,xmlworker not support chinese,so you should edit the source code to support it